# Momentary switch on-off circuit

Tags: circuit-design, design, diy

I am trying to create a circuit to allow me to switch a project on and off with the activation of a momentary switch (a momentary push button or reed switch, for example), but I'm coming up blank and need help.

I have a few parameters:

1. Source voltage is 5v DC
2. Output load is less than 1mA - It's just driving the Enable lead on a chip (Consonance CN5711)
3. Output voltage should be as close to 5v as possible
4. The circuit must be "default on" - when power is first applied, the circuit needs to be on; actuation of the momentary switch would turn the circuit off and leave it off until the next time, and repeated actuation would cycle that (I hope that makes sense)
5. Must draw as little power as possible.

I have a working example of what I need in front of me but the company that made it used several unmarked components that I can't identify and is not willing to provide me that information, so I have to design my own.

Let me know if there's anything else you guys need.

Thanks

Comment: There is no question in this question.

Comment: This can be done with a single flipflop chip configured as a toggle flipflop, or two inverters from a hex inverter, quad NAND gate, etc, or as above a couple of transistors.  Which is your preference?

Comment: Eugene Sh: My apologies.  The question is, 'how can I accomplish this?'

AnalogKid: A couple transistors would be nice, but I'm not opposed to the other options if it means drawing less power from the source to power the circuit

Comment: flipflop, as mentioned above by @AnalogKid. Schmitt trigger input also nice to have, perhaps such as [this](https://www.ti.com/product/SN74HCS74), although it is a dual package with other unnecessary features

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following circuit is one that I modified from [Mosaic Industries](http://www.mosaic-industries.com/embedded-systems/microcontroller-projects/electronic-circuits/push-button-switch-turn-on/latching-toggle-power-switch).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flPjNB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I used a relay in the schematic for ease of testing, but a switch should work equally well.

As per your specs, it starts in the "ON" state. The voltage is near 5V when on, and near ground otherwise. The current draw is minimal. It is designed to deliver 1mA to RL. RL is necessary if your load draws less than 1mA.

There is somewhat of a trade-off between how often one can cycle toggle the circuit, and how immune it is to switch contact bounce. I cannot give an exact figure, for how long the switch needs to be closed for proper operation, but it is somewhere in the vicinity of 50mSec. That allows a toggle rate of about 10/sec. If you want more bounce immunity, C1 can be tweaked, but if tweaked too much other components may need to be tweaked as well.

Comment: Opps.  My bad.  Read the post, saw that, went away for an hour, came back, misremembered the post.  Removed comment.

Comment: Math Keeps Me Busy, I assume that, in this circuit, the relay is my proverbial "push button"?

Comment: Yes. In your actual circuit, use a switch, not a relay. It was easier for me to simulate with a relay than with a push button. If CircuitLab has a method of toggling a button back and forth during a simulation, I didn't see it, so I just wired something up.

Comment: Looks really good.  I'll run with that and see how it goes.  Thanks a million!